# Pandas Pivot the DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

Does anyone know how to use pandas to convert the data frame from the upper one to the lower one? Makes rows of dates become columns of date. Thanks

```
date        time        price
2020-12-24  17:01:00    10
2020-12-24  17:00:00    11
2020-12-25  17:01:00    11
2020-12-25  17:00:00    12
        
        
time     2020-12-24  2020-12-25
17:01:00    10       11
17:00:00    11       12
```

Answer (score 3):

Check `T`

```
out = df.pivot(*df.columns).T
Out[390]: 
date      2020-12-24  2020-12-25
time                            
17:00:00          11          12
17:01:00          10          11

#df.pivot(columns='date',index='time',values='price')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['time', 'date'])['Price'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
date      2020-12-24  2020-12-25
time                            
17:00:00          11          12
17:01:00          10          11
```